# Placing Images in the css file instead of the html file

Tags: html, css, image

For my header I'm using the ul and li tags for my nav menu (Portfolio/Contact/About) I'm trying to place the images text (Portfolio/Contact/About) and the slashes in the CSS file instead of my div "navigationMain" in the HTML file but every attempt I tried has failed. Is there a certain way dealing with ul, li tags and placing images within the tags using CSS? Because I've placed my logo and header background in the header within the css file. Also I'm creating this website in notepadd++

http://jsfiddle.net/J4h9Q/7/embedded/result/ http://jsfiddle.net/J4h9Q/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container"> 
<div class="headerMain">  </div>
<div class="navigationMain"> 
<ul class="nav">
<li><img src="images/portfolio2.png" alt="portfolio" id="portfoliobutton"></li>
<li><img src="images/slash.png" alt="slash"></li>
<li><img src="images/about.png" alt="about" id="aboutbutton"></li>
<li><img src="images/slash.png" alt="slash"></li>
<li id="contactbutton" class="contact"><img src="images/contact.png" alt="contact"></li> 
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,div,ul,li,p{ 
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

html,body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
background: url(../images/background11.png) repeat scroll 0 0; 
}

.header {
background: black;
height: 165px;
min-width: 1075px;
}


.container {
height: 165px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 1075px; 
}


.headerMain{
 height: 165px; 
 position: relative;
 width: 195px;
 float: left;
 left: 20px;
 top: 4px;
 background:url(../images/ARlogo8.png) no-repeat center center; 
 }


.navigationMain{
height: 154px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: -4px;
position: relative;
width: 665px;
right: 30px;
}



li{
display: inline;
}

.nav li{   
display: inline;
color:white;
position: relative;
top: 70px;
font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
left: 160px;
font-size:44px;
}
```

Comment: The more interesting question is why does your linking to your images fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How tied are you to putting the images in CSS? I recommend putting the slashes, if anything, in the CSS. That would immediately reduce the number of list items down to 3 - so it's more "semantic". You should not have a list item just to denote a slash.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/YBzA9/1/
*Feel free to tweak the dimensions in `.nav a` when you use your real images.*

After you reduce the number of list items, consider one of the following:

- (easy solution) putting the images inside of anchor tags in the markup and calling it a day
- (a more "correct" solution) styling your anchor like such:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" id="portfolio-link">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="about-link">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="contact-link">Contact</a></li>
</ul
```

**CSS**

```
.nav li {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/26x34/000000/fff&text=//');
    padding-left: 26px;
}
.nav li:first-child {
    background: none;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -999px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 120px;
}

#portfolio-link {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/146x35/000000/fff&text=Portfolio');
}
#about-link {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/146x35/000000/fff&text=About');
}
#contact-link {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/146x35/000000/fff&text=Contact');
}
```

This allows text to still be read (search engines, screen readers) but still maintain visual appeal.

Comment: it worked, is there any chance you could explain more about this css .nav li {
    background: url(../images/slash.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 26px;
}
.nav li:first-child {
    background: none;
}
.nav a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 150px;

}

Comment: Each list item has the slash as a background, so you don't have to add it to your markup. However, you don't want to add a slash in front of EVERY list item, only between the list items. So the first list item should not have a bg image (that explains the :first-child).

Comment: a is typically an inline element, so you need to change it to display: block to define a height/width on it. I did a text indent because my markup has text in it; without the text indent, text will appear on top of your bg image. Try to look at the fiddle and comment out certain properties to see how they affect things, it'd be a great way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You could set that images as background without repeating it. You also need to set a min height and width to be sure that you can see the image later. You can also store the image in the css file if you store it base64 encoded.

In general I would just fix the links to your images. Try using absolute urls beginning with a single slash.